# Underscore Template does not get rendered. Why?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a template for Underscore.js that does not get rendered. My problem is explained in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/my3NW/).

```
// this string will get loaded by an ajax call and put in a variable when the application starts
var allTemplates = '<section id="header">header template</section>    <section id="content"><% var test = 10 %><%= test %></section>"';

// put it in the DOM to parse it with jQuery
$('#test').html(allTemplates);




var getSpecificTemplate = function(templateID) {
    return $('#test').find('#' + templateID).html();   
};

var templateData = getSpecificTemplate('content');

// expected log output: 10
// actual log output: &lt;% var test = 10 %&gt;&lt;%= test %&gt; 
console.log( _.template(templateData, {}) );

// why?
```

This setup equals pretty much my code. What could be the problem? Why is the template even encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine. What you have missed on is the call to `.html()`.
Your `templateData` variable is messed up because `.html()` in this line -

```
return $('#test').find('#' + templateID).html();
```

escapes the content. Change `.html()` to `.text()` and this should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5Q7e/

**Edit: CORRECT APPROACH** -

The above doesn't work because `.text()` only gets the 'text', skipping the elements.
What you need to do is, add your template in a `script` tag and not `section` tag. This way,
when you make a `.html()` call on the element, you will get unescaped html (jQuery doesn't bother escaping when `.html()` is called on a `script` tag).

Here, make this change

OLD

```
var allTemplates = '<section id="header">header template</section>    <section id="content"><% var test = 10 %><%= test %></section>"';
```

NEW

```
var allTemplates = '<section id="header">header template</section>    <script type="text/template" id="content"><a href="#“><% var test = 10 %><%= test %></a></script>"';
```

I couldn't get this to work with jsfiddle.net, so here is a [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQoPULfHEi5GCUo19Vlt?p=preview)

Comment: I tried this too, but what I have these templates to render HTML. when using `.text()`, it ignores those HTML tags: http://jsfiddle.net/my3NW/4/

Comment: @dislick you had this character `“` instead of `"` in your fiddle so your `a` tag was never getting closed. Replace that and you see your output, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/my3NW/5/

Comment: @dislick, you are right. `.text()` doesn't get the html elements. Check my edit for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're not evaluating your template, you're appending a literal string.

Change this: `$('#test').html(allTemplates);`

to this:

```
var templateString = _.template(allTemplates, {});
$('#test').html(templateString);
```

Then you will see the expected outcome in your `console.log()`, also in your `console.log()` you can simply put the following:

```
var templateData = getSpecificTemplate('content');
console.log(templateData);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/my3NW/6/

Hope this helps!

Comment: What does jQuery's [`html` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml) do when you hand it a function and what error do you think will happen when you `$('#test').html(_.template(allTemplates))`?

Comment: @muistooshort it will empty the element before appending the new html? I can't see any errors other than the IE issues with absolute hrefs and html5 elements? Perhaps you could spell it out for me? :)

Comment: It will execute the function and pass it arguments that the template won't be expecting so you will almost always trigger ReferenceError exceptions. In this specific case, the only template-ish stuff in the template is `<% var test = 10 %><%= test %>` so it will probably work by accident; a real template will raise an exception though.

Comment: @muistooshort Ahh, cool. Thanks for that. I didn't think of that. So evaluate the template before passing it to `.html()`?

Comment: Yup. The unexpected behavior of `.html` when handed a template can lead to puzzling results, best to evaluate the template function by hand and hand a string to `.html`.